# Узнать, в каком режиме открыт файл

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015

Я открываю файл:`fopen_s(&file, filepath, mode);`
Возможно ли узнать какой-нибудь функцикцией от `file`, в каком режиме открыт файл: `"r", "w", "r+", "w+", "a", "a+"`?

Comment: Почему бы и дальше не использовать значение переменной `mode`?

Comment: @PavelParshin дело в том, что нет переменной `mode`,я сначала открываю файл в "r+", если файла нет - то в "w". И так для нескольких файлов. Не удобно было бы хранить кучу режимов в отдельном векторе для каждого файла

Comment: Насколько надёжное нужно решение? Для каких ОС, компиляторов?

Comment: @ixSci сейчас добавлю в метки вопроса. Что имеется в виду под надежностью?

Comment: Переносимых решений не существует. Можно попробовать варианты из вопроса на [английском SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025785/c-file-operations-check-opened-file-pointer-access-mode).

Comment: @Dmitry, можно написать обертку над `FILE` с хранением текущего режима.

Comment: @alexolut проверил на своей студии: для `FILE* Ptr` не существует члена `_flag`. В моем случает только `_Placeholder`.

Comment: @PavelParshin тоже склоняюсь к этому...